# Need help finding conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$\overline{z-2+4i} = 2z+3+8i$$

I got this question on my online assignment. I got to a point where I couldn't get rid of the conjugate of z and I don't know how to expand or what to do with it. I would send you guys a screenshot of my solutions but I already uploaded my answer. Can you guys help me understand this question? I have uploaded an image of the question.

Comment: Try to type your question directly here using MathJax. Read the easy directions that the site offers.

Answer (score 3):

Write $z=a+bi$ and use the mentioned properties and then compare the real and imaginary parts. So you will have:

$$a-bi - 2 - 4i = 2a + 2bi + 3 + 8i \implies \begin{cases} a-2 = 2a + 3 \\ -b-4=2b+8 \end{cases}$$

You can continue from here.

Comment: Why do you take z = a + bi? It's not given.

Comment: @user3504306 Every complex number is of the form $a+bi$, right?

Comment: true. Forgot about that